# c++ How to read a structured data and skip the first row of table header?

Tags: c++

The data are similar to the following forms.

```
Name Language Mathematics  // the head line
Xiaoming 89 56
Xiaofang 48 48
```

I want to manipulate through the structure and skip the first line, how should I do it?

```
#included <iosteam>
#included <string>
using namespace std;
struct Student{
   string name;
   double language;
   double mathematics;
}student;
void readdata(string infile,string outfile){
  ifstream in(infile);
  string headline;
  getline(in,headline);
  while(in.read(&student, sizeof(student))!=NULL){   //?
     ....
  }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  string infile, outfile;
  for(int i=0;i<argc;i++){
     if(strcmp(argv[i],"-i"))
       infile=argv[i+1];
     if(strcmp(argv[i],"-o"))
       outfile=argv[i+1];
  }
  readdata(infile,outfile);
}
```

In the above code, the line with the question mark in the comment, i.e. in.read(&student,sizeof(student))! =NULL,there is a compilation problem,is there a better way to read the structure with a stream file

Comment: what is the compilation problem?

Comment: `NULL` is C.... don't use it. checking `in.read(&student, sizeof(student))` will call the [`operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), which is sufficient.

Comment: also this not will read the file the way you want it to

Comment: You should use formatted input (`>>`), not `read()`

Comment: by the way, how does `#included` compile for you? what compiler are you using? And <iosteam>?

Answer (score 0):

Do it [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/4x18P3Pzq)

```cpp
  {
      string headline;
      getline(in,headline); // clear heading data
  }
  for (std::string line; getline(in, line);) { // Read all lines
      
      Student student;
      
      std::istringstream ss{line};
      ss >> student.name;
      ss >> student.language;
      ss >> student.mathematics;

      // do_something_with(student)
  }
```

Other pointers:

- Try to not use static variables
- Do not use NULL
- I would recommend you to use c++ string comparison instead of strcmp, ie `argv[i] == "-o"s` (after requires you to use `using namespace std::literals`)

On request:

### Argument comparison

https://godbolt.org/z/Yhvxoecfz

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Note that if you have a old compiler that does not support string_view
    // you can just as well use std::string
    std::vector<std::string_view> args(argv + 1, argv + argc); // Exclude the program name

    for (auto s: args){ // Iterate through the args, only works for stand alone arguments
        if (s == "-x") { // Compare a single element
            std::cout << "do x\n";
        }
        // ... etc
    }
    
    // Version two: when some arguments requires you to look at the next argument
    for (size_t i = 0; i < args.size(); ++i) {
        auto arg = args.at(i);
        if (arg == "-i") {
            ++i; // Select the next argument
            std::cout << "in file: " << args.at(i); // I is now pointing at the next
        }
        else if (arg == "--single-argument") {
            std::cout << "this is a regular argument";
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "unknown argument " << arg << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

or we could modify your code a bit

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <string_view>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  string infile, outfile;
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    auto arg = std::string_view{argv[i]};
    if (arg == "-i") {
      ++i;
      infile = argv[i];
    }
    if (arg == "-o") {
      ++i;
      outfile = argv[i];
    }
  }
  // readdata(infile, outfile);
}
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of c++ string comparison instead of strcmp ? Same function as strcmp above。t

Comment: @fangjh Added two examples, the last one should be relevant to your application

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late and the answer is good. However, I would propose to add additional encapsulation and overload operator>>

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class Student{
private:
   std::string name;
   double language;
   double mathematics;
public:
    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& is, Student& s) {
        return is >> s.name >> s.language >> s.mathematics;
    }
};

void ReadData(std::string inFileName){
  std::ifstream in(inFileName);
  {
    std::string headline;
    getline(in, headline);
  }
  for(Student student; in >> student;) {   //?
     
  }
}
```

Comment: Works for the test case but would be confused if the number of elements per line would happend to differ

Comment: @Lasersköld yeah, but then you would have a bigger design issue. Also, it's the same for your answer: if the order of the elements would change, or they would insert other elements, it will also break....